# Parsing multiple text files and recreating them to a set template

Tags: parsing, batch-file

I'm not very experienced in batch programming. I've sort of hobbled together various pieces of code but it does not quite work as I want it too.

Here is the problem. Log files are created in a directory. Some are multiple entries some are single entries. They all follow a specific pattern. F.ex.

```
    START STRING 1234
    NAME1 ADRESS1 ETC
    NAME2 ADRESS2 ETC
    NAME3 ADRESS3 ETC
```

Sometimes there are more then one name entry in a single file, sometimes it's just a single entry. All the files have the starting string. What I need to do is parse these log files and recreate them in another directory, one file for each name in a file, each in the format of a single named file. Using the above example, it would create 3 files, each looking like this:

```
    START STRING
    NAME ADRESS ETC
```

Here is the code sofar. It sort of works.. except when there is more then one log file in the directory at a time, I end up with a few entries with just two START STRING in them, which I need to avoid. In other words, I need it to go through each log file separately instead of, as I assume it does, treat all the log files as one single large text file.

```
    @Echo off
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion


    :::First find out how many lines a file has.
    Set _File=*.log
    Set /a _Lines=0
    For /f %%j in ('Type %_File%^|Find "" /v /c') Do Set /a _Lines=%%j
    set /a "linecount= _Lines"


    :::Grab the first line always and then create a new file depending on how many         lines the file contained
    :LOOP
    if %linecount% GEQ 2 ( 
        set /a "linecount = linecount - 1"
        set lines=1 %linecount%
        set curr=1
            for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type *.log') do (
                    for %%b in (!lines!) do (
                    if !curr!==%%b echo %%a >> c:\temp\logs\%linecount%.log
                    )
                set /a "curr = curr + 1"
            )
    )
    if %linecount% GEQ 2 (GOTO LOOP)
    endlocal
```

I'm pretty sure there's a more clever way to do this but this is as far as I've gotten. Wondering if I could simply match the start string and remove it somehow, without removing that first line or, preferably, avoiding getting the double start string all together.

Comment: If a log file have more than one name, which one you want to preserve? The first one? The last one?

Comment: The original log files names do not really matter since once they've been parsed they are going to be removed. It does not matter what the files are called once they have been parsed either. In this example they'll just be called 2.log, 3.log etc etc

Comment: In my humble opinion, if you change your question requirements at some time after posted the question, you should wait much more time before close the question as "solved"; otherwise you are disregarding the people that read your question at first, when it was incomplete and can't be solved... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
:: directories in question
SET destdir=c:\destdir
SET sourcedir=c:\sourcedir
SET /a filecount=0
:: process each .log file in source
FOR %%f IN (%sourcedir%\*.log) DO (
 SET "startline="
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i IN ("%%f") DO (
  IF DEFINED startline (
   CALL :nextfname
   >>!filename! ECHO(%%i
  ) ELSE (
   SET "startline=%%i"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :eof
::
:: Write the header line to the next NEW destination file
::
:nextfname
SET "filename=%destdir%\%filecount%.log"
SET /a filecount+=1
IF EXIST %filename% GOTO nextfname
>>%filename% ECHO(%startline%
GOTO :eof
```

This should do what you appear to want - IIUC, from each `.log` file in the source, create a file in the destination containing 2 lines - the name line after the start line from the corresponding source logfile. (well, if that's not what you want, that's what this routine will do...)

- It processes each filename in the source directory, applied to `%%f`.
- at each new filename, clears `startline`
- assigns the content of the first line to `startline`
- for each remaining line,
- - sets `filename` to a fresh filename in the destination and writes the startline to it
- - outputs the name line in `%%i` to the filename generated.

Note that the `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` allows `!filename!` to refers to the contents of `filename` as it changes in the context of the `FOR...%%i...`

The routine `:nextfilename` is in its own context, so %var% is used in its more familiar meaning. The routine simply establishes a name from `filecount` and increments `filecount`, checks whether the file already exists, and repeats until a brand-new filename is found. The header line is then written to that filename.

Answer (score 1):

The description of you problem is not clear, but judging from your code, I assume you simply want to recreate each log file in a new folder, preserving only the first two lines of each original file.

If so, then this is all you need:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "sourceMask=.\*.log"
set "targetPath=test"
set "keepCount=2"

for %%F in ("%sourceMask%") do (
  <"%%~F" (
    for /l %%N in (1 1 %keepCount% ) do (
      set "ln="
      set /p "ln="
      echo(!ln!
    )
  ) >"%targetPath%\%%~nxF"
)
```

Limitations:

- Lines must end with `<CR><LF>` (Windows style), not `<LF>` (unix style)
- Lines must not exceed 1021 bytes (not including line terminators)
- Trailing control characters will be stripped from the line.

*The above solution does not meet the OP's needs based on comment*

---

***EDIT: Attempt 2 based on refined requirements in OP's commment (untested)***

Blank lines will be ignored - probably a good thing.

The code is intended to be rubust. It should handle any characters in the string, including lines starting with `;` (or any other character), and lines containing `!`. That is the reason for the odd FOR /F option string, and the delayed expansion toggling.

Line lengths are limited to approximately 8191 bytes.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "sourceMask=.\*.log"
set "targetPath=test"
set "targetName=0"

for %%F in ("%sourceMask%") do (
  set "startString="
  for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("%%~F") do (
    if not defined startString (set "startString=%%A") else (
      set "nameString=%%A"
      set /a targetName+=1
      setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
      (
        echo(!startString!
        echo(!nameString!
      ) >"!targetPath!\!targetName!.log"
      endlocal
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Ah, I apologise that my description was a bit vague. If there are 3 names in a file, I need it to create 3 separate files each starting with the START STRING on one line and the name on the next line. The problem arises when there are say, two log files in the directory. It then treats them as one big file which means the START STRING will appear twice in one of the files, since my program simply always adds the first line to each new files. And for some reason it treats multiple files as one large text file, meaning that the start string appears multiple times.

Comment: @user2463125 - OK, I think I understand your requirements now. Check out my 2nd attempt in the revised answer.